# Angular 9 - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular, customvalidator, angular-reactive-forms

I am running an application using Angular CLI 9.0.7. In this application there is a form with a field that needs to have its control digit validated. For this, I created a Custom Validator.

When the field on the form is changed, the Custom Validator is activated to check the consistency.

The Custom Validator component, needs to call a method that is in another class and that is shared by other components, and when it is going to execute this line I get the message Cannot read property '**isCpf**' of undefined.

I copied what is called inside the custom validator, and passed, but this is not correct, it sucks.

How can I do to call the method isCpf correctly and using good practices?

**This is my Custom Validator**

```
    static cpfValido(control: AbstractControl): any | null {
        const cpf: string = control.value;

        if (cpf === '') {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            if (this.isCpf(cpf)) {  // When isCpf is called throw Cannot read property 'isCpf' of undefined
                null;
            }
            else {
                return { 'cpfValido': false };

            }
        }
    }
```

and in the same file this is a called method

```
    private static isCpf(pNumeroCpf: string): boolean {
        if (!pNumeroCpf) return false;

        let nro: string = this.preencherComCaracterEsquerda(this.removerFormatacao(pNumeroCpf), this.SIZE_CPF, '0');
        let j: number = 0;
        let peso: number = 2;
        let soma: number = 0;
        let dvc: number[] = [0, 0];
        let dvi: number[] = [0, 0];

        if (this.temCaracterRepetido(nro)) return false;

        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            peso = 2;

            soma = this.aplicarPeso(nro.substring(0, nro.length - 2 + j), peso, 11);

            dvc[j] = (soma % 11) < 2 ? 0 : 11 - (soma % 11);
        }

        dvi[0] = parseInt(nro.charAt(nro.length - 2), 10);
        dvi[1] = parseInt(nro.charAt(nro.length - 1), 10);

        return (dvi[0] === dvc[0] && dvi[1] === dvc[1]);
    }
```

Comment: What is the class containing these methods called?

Comment: The first red flag I see is that you're using `this` within a `static class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static members are referenced by the class name followed by their name. See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#static-properties) for more info.

So in your case it would be

```js
export class ValidatorClass {
  static cpfValido(control: AbstractControl): any | null {
      const cpf: string = control.value;

      if (cpf === '') {
          return null;
      }
      else {
          if (ValidatorClass.isCpf(cpf)) {  // <-- use class name instead of `this`
              null;
          }
          else {
              return { 'cpfValido': false };

          }
      }
  }
  .
  .
}
```

I assume here that your class name is `ValidatorClass`. Please replace it with your actual class name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to call `this` within a `static class`. You can't do that. `static classes` are supposed to be pure.

Here's an example of what's happening:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  static getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
  getNameWorks() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

const person = new Person('Joe');
// Non static method
console.log(person.getNameWorks());
// Exception
console.log(person.getName());
```

You can access static methods by doing `ClassName.method()`, but keep in mind, you can't use `this` within `static classes`

So you could do something like this instead:

```js
class Person {
  constructor() { }
  static sayHello(text) {
    alert(text);
  }
}

Person.sayHello('hello');
```

With that being said, it looks like you can just replace:

`this.isCpf(cpf)`

with

`WhateverTheClassNameIs.isCpf(cpf)`